# Kinda stuck in a while loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I just dont see the reason while my code behaves like this

```
        private int getRandomId(string idpool)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int id = rnd.Next(1, 9999);
        if (idpool == "vm")
        {
            if (vms != null)
            {
                foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vms)
                {
                    if (vm.id == id)
                    { return 0; }

                }

                return id;
            }
        }
        if (idpool == "job")
        {
            if (vms != null)
            {
                foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vms)
                {
                    foreach (Job job in vm.jobs)
                    {
                        if (job.id == id)
                        { return 0; }
                    }

                }

                return id;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Code2.

```
                int id;
            if (jobCreate_monday.Checked)
            {
                id = getRandomId("job");
                while (id == 0)
                { getRandomId("job"); }
                current_vm.jobs.Add(new Job(id, jobCreate_start.Value.Hour, jobCreate_start.Value.Minute, jobCreate_stop.Value.Hour, jobCreate_stop.Value.Minute, "Monday"));
            }
            if (jobCreate_tuesday.Checked)
            {
                id = getRandomId("job");
                while (id == 0)
                { getRandomId("job"); }
                current_vm.jobs.Add(new Job(id, jobCreate_start.Value.Hour, jobCreate_start.Value.Minute, jobCreate_stop.Value.Hour, jobCreate_stop.Value.Minute, "Tuesday"));

            }.......more days.
```

Now if only monday or only tuesday is checked everything works perfectly fine.
as soon as two of them or more are checked the program freezes. 
maybe i dont see something obvious?

best regards.

Comment: In your `while` loop, you're not assigning the result of `getRandomId` to `id`, so `id` never changes and you get an infinite loop.

Comment: You're not reassigning the `id` inside the while loop: `id = getRandomId("job"); while (id == 0) id = getRandomId("job");`

Comment: oh my. i need some coffee. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never assign id to the random id inside the loop

```
 id = getRandomId("job");
while (id == 0)
{ getRandomId("job"); }
```

should be

```
 id = getRandomId("job");
while (id == 0)
{ id = getRandomId("job"); }
```